# Can't send cURL request (POST)

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send cURL request to get response from payment service.
The cURL request looks like:

```
curl -X POST https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/user/oauth/authorize \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET'
```

My code in Symfony is:

```
 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/user/oauth/authorize");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        http_build_query(array(
            "grant_type" => "client_credentials",
            "client_id" => $client_id,
            "client_secret" => $client_secret
        ))
 );
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

 curl_close($ch);

 var_dump($server_output);
```

But I always got false. What should I do to send curl request and get answer from payment service?

Comment: Have you tried dropping the call to `http_build_query`? You can pass an array directly to `curl_setopt`, and then the right `Content-Type` will also be set.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
         "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret");

Comment: No, I mean `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("grant_type" => "client_credentials", ...));`

Comment: But actually, when I run your exact code, it seems to work fine already. Are you sure you have the right value for `$client_id` and `$client_secret`?

Comment: Sorry, my earlier suggestion about passing just an array seems wrong. Please ignore that. :-) As I said, your code seems to work as-is.

Comment: Note that it seems you've leaked a valid client secret here. Please immediately take whatever steps are necessary to invalidate this client secret, and if this is a production system, contact the provider and see what other steps might be necessary.

Comment: can u show your working code? cause even I try to send curl with paramenetrs from example I got false

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code. I used `$client_id = '145227'; $client_secret = '12f071174cb7eb79d4aac5bc2f07563f';`, the values from your `curl` command.

Comment: Try adding curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); If it works then read up a bit on curl and ssl.

Comment: Please provide the result of `curl_error($ch)`.